# How to combine these build rules

Tags: c++, makefile

I was provided with the first build rule, but I wanted to also link the cpp files inside `$(UTILS_DIR)`, so I just copied the first one and modified it slightly. So I have these individually but not sure how to merge them. Kinda works but think it's a bit hacky as I have literally no idea what I'm doing.

I had to add `$(SDW_COMPILER_FLAGS)` because otherwise for any file inside `src/utils` I had to do `#include "../sdw/File.h"` whereas now I can do `#include <File.h>`.

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SDW_DIR)%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTIONS) -c -o $@ $^ $(SDL_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(GLM_COMPILER_FLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(UTILS_DIR)%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_OPTIONS) -c -o $@ $^ $(SDL_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(GLM_COMPILER_FLAGS) $(SDW_COMPILER_FLAGS)
```

These are some of the variables referenced in the above rules:

```
SDW_DIR := ./libs/sdw/
UTILS_DIR := ./src/utils/
GLM_DIR := ./libs/glm-0.9.7.2/

SDW_SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard $(SDW_DIR)*.cpp)
SDW_OBJECT_FILES := $(patsubst $(SDW_DIR)%.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(SDW_SOURCE_FILES))
UTILS_SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard $(UTILS_DIR)*.cpp)
UTILS_OBJECT_FILES := $(patsubst $(UTILS_DIR)%.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(UTILS_SOURCE_FILES))

SDW_COMPILER_FLAGS := -I$(SDW_DIR)
UTILS_COMPILER_FLAGS := -I$(UTILS_DIR)
GLM_COMPILER_FLAGS := -I$(GLM_DIR)
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you want to do.  Why do you want to "merge them"?  Also, I don't have any idea what you mean by "CTRL+C not closing the SDL window".  I don't know what an "SDL window" is or what it has to do with a makefile running a compiler; makefiles and compilers don't (generally) open windows.  Also you haven't made clear what the difference is here, other than the source file location (what the point of the `SDW_COMPILER_FLAGS` variable is).

Comment: @MadScientist I've edited the question to remove some stuff and add clarification

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to combine these rules.  They are compiling source files from different directories and need different flags, so why should they be created using the same rule?  There are tricks you could use but I'm not sure that they are going to make things much easier.